# foreach loop with a condition perl?

Tags: perl, for-loop

Is it possible to have a `foreach` loop with a condition in Perl?

I'm having to do a lot of character by character processing - where a `foreach` loop is very convenient.  Note that I cannot use some libraries since this is for school.

I could write a `for` loop using `substr` with a condition if necessary, but I'd like to avoid that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should show us some code, including the sort of thing you would *like* to do.

In general, character-by-character processing of a string would be done in Perl by writing

```
for my $ch (split //, $string) { ... }
```

or, if it is more convenient

```
my @chars = split //, $string;
for (@chars) { ... }
```

or

```
my $i = 0;
while ($i < @chars) { my $char = $chars[$i++]; ... }
```

and the latter form can support multiple expressions in the `while` condition. Perl is very rich with different ways to do the similar things, and without knowing more about your problem it is impossible to say which is best for you.

---

**Edit**

It is important to note that none of these methods allow the original string to be modified. If that is the intention then you must use [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), [`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) or [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).

Note that `substr` has a fourth parameter that will *replace* the specified part of the original string. Note also that it can act as an *lvalue* and so take an assignment. In other words

```
substr $string, 0, 1, 'X';
```

can be written equivalently as

```
substr($string, 0, 1) = 'X';
```

If `split` is used to convert a string into a list of characters (actually one-character strings) then it can be modified in this state and recombined into a string using `join`. For instance

my @chars = split //, $string;
   $chars[0] = 'X';
   $string = join '', @chars;

does a similar thing to the above code using `substr`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Splitting then doing the while loop is the best option for me.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
foreach my $l (@something) {
  last if (condition);
  # ...
}
```

will exit the loop if condition is true

Comment: This would definitely work.  I try to stay away from "last" or breaks though :)

Answer (score 1):

You might investigate the [`next`](http://p3rl.org/next) and [`last`](http://p3rl.org/last) directives. More info in [`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control).